# Intermittent "Page Not Found" when using Django through Pydev

Tags: python, django, eclipse, ide, pydev

I recently started developing Django using Pydev in Eclipse, along with several other people I know, and I keep losing several hours of productivity a day to this error that I can't seem to debug.  Essentially, sometimes after starting up my django run configuration, I'll go to the URL `http://127.0.0.1:8000/foo` and it simply spits me back this response:

```
<h1>Page not found: /foo</h1>
```

At first I could reproduce this behavior all the time; any time I had multiple workspaces of eclipse open and shut down my Django server once, the server wouldn't actually shut down, but it would just keep serving the page not founds until I shut down both instances of Eclipse.

Stopping doing that and it seemed to work, but then it intermittently seemed to start back up again.  When this happens, it will literally not stop happening until I close eclipse, and the eclipse.exe process will hang (and continue to server Page not found pages) until I manually go into the process and kill it.  Sometimes, that won't even fix it, and it'll break itself the first time I try to start Django back up.

I'm on the stable build of PyDev and Eclipse 3.6.1.

Any idea what's going on?  This is unbelievable frustrating, especially because I tend to like the IDE with this exception.

Answer (score 1):

Are you by any chance using a run configuration to launch your development server? Because that kept happening to me too. It seems that eclipse isn't cleanly closing django when you stop it from the IDE and it's holding on to the http port. In that sense you're sending requests to a zombie server instance, hence the not founds. I have since resorted to launching django from the command line. Not the prettiest solution, I admit.

Comment: Yes!  I am.  I've been assuming I've been doing...something, because everyone I'm working with is using it too and had no issues like this.  If I'm not doing something wrong, this is a really nasty bug to have in :\.